# Change file after each run in python without for loop

Tags: python

I have a code which read three files, two files remain same(unchanged), the third one needs to change after each run. In the code below the file named `run1-rbd-new.rbd`. I have thirt of these kind of files that I need to change after every run. Rightnow, I am doing manually to change the name of the file.

Is it possible I can automate that each run, it changes the file automatically, like run*-rbd-new.rbd.

```
file1 = "original-impact.rbd"
file2 = "run1-rbd-new.rbd"
file_inv = "readback_adder_inverted.rbd"

src1 = open (file1,'r')
src2 = open (file2,'r')
src3= open(file_inv,'r')

num_lines_nonbram = 1891426 # non-bram data from line 102 to 1891426 write 1891427 b/c loops works one line minus and its non-bram data num_lines_bram; write for time being changed it later
num_lines = 2432181 # for Artix-7
num_bits = 77829792 # for Artix-7
bits_perline = 32
del_lines = 101   # number of header lines; must be deleted


num_bit_flip_zeros = 0
num_bit_flip_ones = 0
num_same_bits = 0
Total_bit_flip = 0
Total_bits = 0
Total_lut_bits = 0
Total_non_lut_bits = 0
total_bit_flips = 0


lut_bit_flip_at_0 = 0

non_lut_bit_flip_at_0 = 0

lut_bit_flip_at_1 = 0

non_lut_bit_flip_at_1 = 0

i=0
while i < del_lines:
 line1 = src1.readline()
 line2 = src2.readline()
 line_inv = src3.readline()     
 i+=1

i=0
j=0
k=0

while i < (num_lines_nonbram-del_lines):

      line1 = src1.readline() 
      line2 = src2.readline()
      line_inv = src3.readline()
      while k < bits_perline:

       if ((line1[k] == "0" and line_inv[k]== "0" and line2[k] == "0" or line1[k] == "1" and line_inv[k]== "1" and line2[k] == "1" )):


        num_same_bits += 1

       else:

        if (line1[k]=="0" and line2[k]=="1"): 
         num_bit_flip_zeros += 1

        if (line1[k]=="1"  and line2[k]=="0"): 
         num_bit_flip_ones += 1

        if ((line1[k] == "0" and line_inv[k]== "1" and line2[k] == "1")):

         lut_bit_flip_at_0 += 1

        if ((line1[k] == "0" and line_inv[k]== "0" and line2[k] == "1")):

         non_lut_bit_flip_at_0 += 1

        if ((line1[k] == "1" and line_inv[k]== "0" and line2[k] == "0")):

         lut_bit_flip_at_1 += 1


        if ((line1[k] == "1" and line_inv[k]== "1" and line2[k] == "0")):

         non_lut_bit_flip_at_1 += 1


       k +=1
      k = 0
      i+=1

Total_bit_flip = num_bit_flip_zeros + num_bit_flip_ones

Total_lut_bits = lut_bit_flip_at_0+lut_bit_flip_at_1

Total_non_lut_bits = non_lut_bit_flip_at_0+non_lut_bit_flip_at_1

print "-----------------------------------"
print file2
print "Number of bit flips at 0 = %d" %num_bit_flip_zeros + '\n' "Number of bit flips at 1 = %d" %num_bit_flip_ones +'\n' "Total number of bit flips = %d" %Total_bit_flip + '\n'

print "-----------------------------------"

print "Number of lut bits @0 = %d" %lut_bit_flip_at_0 + '\n' + "Number of lut bit @1 = %d" %lut_bit_flip_at_1 + '\n'+ "Number of non-lut bits @0 = %d" %non_lut_bit_flip_at_0  + '\n' + "Number of non-lut bits@1 = %d" %non_lut_bit_flip_at_1 
print "-----------------------------------"
print "Verification"
print "Total bits at zero = %d" %num_bit_flip_zeros  + "= %d" %(lut_bit_flip_at_0+non_lut_bit_flip_at_0)

print "Total bits at ones = %d" %num_bit_flip_ones +"= %d"    %(lut_bit_flip_at_1+non_lut_bit_flip_at_1)
src2.close()
src1.close()
```

Comment: Please keep a steady indentation, recommend indenting 4 spaces each time. There’s places in your code you indented 1 space and other where your indented 5 spaces, that’s a big no-no. Can’t believe you hadn’t trigger an indentation error yet

Comment: Try using `os.rename()`

Comment: Nice suggestion

Comment: Didnt get error because same indentation in loop

Comment: @John os.rename used to change the file name. Would you explain a little how to do ?

Comment: `os.rename(path_to_current_filename, path_to_new_filename)`